# 3D view of a thickness raster

Tags: qgis, grass-gis

I have a thickness raster and sediment core data (collected within the raster area in excel format).

Is there any option to create a 3D view of a thickness raster incorporating with core length?

Comment: What format is the sediment core data?

Comment: Yes, please check this overview page: https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Help_with_3D (not all functions will be exposed to QGIS, though, hence you may want to use GRASS GIS directly for this task).